# LINQ grouping and ignoring column

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, group-by, linq-to-objects

I'm using EF and LINQ.
I have the following in my db table

```
branchId      Name        ItemId          CategoryId
2             Test1       1               1
5             Test1       1               1
3             Test1       1               2
2             Test2       2               1
7             Test2       2               1
```

I need to group by ItemId and BranchId should be ignored, so the output should be

```
Name  ItemId  CategoryId
Test1 1       1
Test1 1       2
Test2 2       2
```

Please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply group by which is on multiple column, so for that you need to go for code like as below which do group by on multiple columns....

```
var numberGroups = from it in context.items
                   group it by new { it.ItemId,it.Name,it.CateogryID } into g
                   select new { ItemID = g.Key.ItemID, Name= g.Key.Name
                                CategoryID = g.Key.CategoryID };
```

Comment: doesn't work. i can't group by it.ItemId and it.CategoryId ??

Comment: when I start typing group it by it.ContentObjectId,... after the "," it tells me "Can not resolve symbol"

Comment: @PranayRana `item` is the name Shane Km used to represent the collection of items, you need to replace that with a reference to your table object e.g. something like `context.items`

Comment: @PranayRana even if it's *just* for reference (the count-thing is a nice idea) you **should** add it to the text - that would be far less confusing! otherwise - just remove the visualisation, as it doesn't do a good job anyways! (it's like talking about the color blue, but drawing a yellow picture to show the effect of contrast when using more or less water - sure ... color is the base, ... but blue may behave differently)

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from item in context.Item
            group by item.Name,ItemId,item.CategoryId
           select item.Name,Item.Id,item.CategoryId;
```

Comment: I have edited my answer before you have reloaded your page :)